# mysqldump: replace drop table in output with delete?

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump, delete

I am using `mysqldump` to dump some records in a table:

```
mysqldump mydatabase mytable --where="field=value"
```

this emits script that includes `drop table mytable` statement.

Since I use the `--where` option, when I replay the script, I want to overwrite only these records that satisfy the condition `field=value`. I want the emitted script to delete just these records:

```
delete from `mytable` where field=value
```

is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify to not use any creation SQL with [--no-create-info](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-create-info)

```
mysqldump mydatabase mytable --no-create-info --where="field=value"
```

If you want to overwrite the records on reload of the mysqldump, just add [--replace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_replace)

```
mysqldump mydatabase mytable --no-create-info --replace --where="field=value"
```

I suggested [--replace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_replace) because [REPLACE is a mechanical DELETE and INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html).

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: thanks. this removes drop/create table. but how do I add the delete statement?

Comment: Updated my answer...

Comment: thanks! suppose after I create a dump, a few more records got added to the table. I need to delete all records which satisfy the condition, and put the ones from the dump. I appreciate your help. looks like I cannot do it with just command line switches.

Comment: probably of little use to the OP today, but for those also searching for an ability to quickly create the delete statements from an insert, this Vim command/function may be a good help: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/16428/11715